# How compile driver on Android TV?

Tags: android, compilation, driver, television, android-tv

I have Android TV and need to connect a pointing device to this TV. But pointing device needs special driver. Supplier send me the driver file *.c format and say I must compile into android kernel. What is the way compile driver on android device and especially this android TV. I can not connect TV to computer - it has no USB fo PC connection, only USB for peripherals. Can you help me what is the way to compile and install android driver in this case ? Thank you for the tip in advance.

Android TV is Philips 48" Philips 48PFT5500, with USb touchframe (unknown brand). Android driver from touchframe is in .c file.

Comment: I don't really know what kind of pointing device requires you to recompile the kernel, but the answer is going be better answered in some of the custom ROM forums.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, not happening. Try to get a pointing device that doesn't need proprietary drivers.

Comment: Sorry, in my case I have device and driver in any format, so I would like to find the sollution for this case. But I haven't got experience, this is why I am asking how to make it. Perhaps it can help also to other people.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can't just compile drivers for an android device, making this question ridiculous on top of the fact that you didn't even bother posting what android TV device and what mouse you're trying to use or anything else that would have been useful if it were possible.

Comment: Sorry for uncomplete question, but dont know which information is required to solve this question. I edited the question with type of TV. Touch device is touchframe (not mouse) I would like integrate to android TV. Also I have android driver in .c file but dont know absolutely how to integrate. I thought exist an universal way to integrate driver.